# Very simple drawing on WPF elements

Tags: wpf, drawing

I must draw many lines on a WPF usercontrol or regular WPF control (like Image / Canvas).
The positions and sizes of the lines stay, but the colors change over time.

- about 2000 lines
- there's no need to reference them or interact with them later, as it would be possible with shapes
- on color update all lines will be drawn again (that's how I did it in WinForms).
- updates happen only on user action, so like every few seconds up to no change in days
- an update should be quick to not impact program performance much

Using a derivation from FrameworkElement, having to override two properties is so much overhead for such a simple task IMHO.

I'd like to accomplish it with as less code as possible, and best performance regarding that it must only be seen on the screen, without events or whatever interaction.

In WinForms it was so easy: you instatiate a graphics object and draw onto it. There I drew the lines on a bitmap and assigned the bitmap to an WinForms-Image. I even had the possibility to scale the lines by changing the size of the Image.

I understand that there's a difference between direct drawing (WinForms) and retained drawing (WPF). May it be retained as much as it wants, there should be a simple solution to create a bunch of lines and assign them to a usercontrol or a regular WPF control!?

Thanks for any help.

Julian

Comment: Deriving from FrameworkElement is too much overhead?  When you create a custom drawn control in WinForms you are still deriving from UserControl, it's the same process.  Derive from FrameworkElement (or Control) and override OnRender using DrawingContext.DrawLine.

Comment: I had good results with [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) its propably the fastest you can get without directly using direct2D or direct3D.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to OnRender and DrawingContext in much the same way as in WinForms, e.g.

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    base.OnRender(drawingContext);

    Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 1);

    foreach(...)
    {
        drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, p1, p2);
    }
}
```